# Generating random numbers in 2d arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to make my program print random numbers between 1000-9999 but I keep getting an error with `String.Format`.

For example if my program worked it would print something like this:

```
7996   2799   2006   2419   1147

7661   5383   8428   6487   3961

2799   8789   6948   8584   8634

7462   5051   4942   5378   1028

9978   1533   7657   4240   7894

6183   6277   9629   2996   8240

8985   9712   3922   2589   5323

8152   4612   6563   9460   3045
```

**Code**

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class SuperRandGame{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Environment();
}}


class Environment
{
    private int[][] table;

    Environment()
    {
        populate();
        output();
    }

    public void populate()
    {
        table = new int[8][5];

        for(int r=0;r<table.length;r++)
        {
            for(int c=0;c<table[0].length;c++)
            table[r][c]= String.format("%2d",(int)(Math.random()*8999+1000) + "  ");
        }

    }

    public void output()
    {
        out.println();
        for(int r=0;r<table.length;r++)
        {
            for(int c=0;c<table[0].length;c++)
            out.print(String.format("%2d",table[r][c]) + "  ");
            out.println();
        }
        out.println();
        out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you specify error?

Comment: You inner loop reads `for(int c=0;c<table[0].length;c++)`. Shouldn't you use `table[r]`?

Comment: public void populate()
    {
        table = new int[8][5];

        for(int r=0;r<table.length;r++)
        {
            for(int c=0;c<table[0].length;c++)
            table[r][c]= String.format("%2d",(int)(Math.random()*8999+1000) + "  ");
        }

Comment: I need to generate randoms numbers 1000-9999 but its not working in the populate void

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **String.format()** methods returns a **String** type. So you cannot store a **String** type in your **int[][]** array.

Comment: i see that's one of the problems i am having. But how can i get my program to generate numbers 1000-9999 in the "public void populate"?

Comment: Hey I fixed my problem I understood what you meant by what i did wrong with the String.format. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Change this line (you have two of them):

```
for(int c=0;c<table[0].length;c++)
```

To:

```
for(int c=0;c<table[i].length;c++) //Note the index "i"
```

You are probably getting an index out of bounds error while using your for loops.